# Python re expression conditional match

Tags: python, regex

To capture both of the following expressions:

```
str1 = "my son is 21 now"
str2 = "son is 21 now"
```

These two re statements and filters each capture one respectively:

```
r1 = re.compile(".* (son)\s+(is)\s+(21) .*")
r2 = re.compile("(son)\s+(is)\s+(21) .*")

m1 = filter(r1.match, [str1, str2])
m2 = filter(r2.match, [str1, str2])
```

How would I combine `r1` and `r2` into one re statement such that both strings will be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest is to make the first capturing group optional in the first regex:

```
(.* )?(son)\s+(is)\s+(21) .*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mC6sQ4/2)

Answer (score 0):

Just put `^`, `.*` inside a group delimited by pipe symbol at the start.

```
r1 = re.compile(r"(?:^|.* )(son)\s+(is)\s+(21) .*")
```

Comment: Wouldn't the additional spaces in there cause issues? `(?:^|.*)(son)\s+(is)\s+(21).*")`

Comment: @Leb yep. without the space , `fooson is 21` will got a match.